# orderby field - list of available options?

Tags: sort

I would like to sort items by the "order" field of the page attributes (see pic).

[image]

I've come across all kinds of "custom tag" solutions but not one listing all of the *already available* fields you can use with orderby. I'd like to use the "order" field as shown in the editor. I'd tried replacing the orderby field in the template with "order" but I don't see any results.

I'm currently using:

```
post_type=projects&order=ASC&orderby=order&offset=1&posts_per_page=100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **menu_order**, like so:

```
post_type=projects&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order&offset=1&posts_per_page=100
```

Vaguely related reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Parameters

Comment: The issues here is, I am not using menus, and all the pages are in "Projects", so they don't appear as menu options.